# Is this wrong or am i missing something ( int count = 10, x; )

Tags: c, objective-c, assignment-operator, variable-assignment

Came across this example in the book im reading and it didn't make sense at all to me, I'm probably missing something but it seems like youre assigning count with the values '10' and then the value 'x' which isnt even an int. Just wondering if this is a syntax that is valid.

The book says this:

The variables count and x are declared to be integer variables in the normal fashion. On the next line, the variable intPtr is declared to be of type “pointer to int.” Note that the two lines of declarations could have been combined into a single line:

```
int count = 10, x, *intPtr;
```

here's the program its taken from:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int count = 10, x;

    int *intPtr;

    intPtr = &count;

    x = *intPtr;

    NSLog (@"count = %i, x = %i", count, x);

    [pool drain];

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: As an aside, combining the two lines of declarations onto a single line is poor practice, since they are not even the same type.  Personally, I don't even like the idea of assigning multiple variables of the same type on the same line, unless they are either all being assigned values or none of them are being assigned values.

Comment: I wouldn't use that syntax. Ugly.

Comment: Thanks folks, That makes sense it just was not looking right to me with the assignment operator thrown in there.

Comment: This is also related to `int* p, i`. Here, only `p` is a pointer, and `i` remains an `int`. The correct way would be `int *p, *i`, and even better would be to split them up. As mentioned, this kind of syntax is fairly ugly.

Comment: ok so I'm not totally crazy, that is cool, i thought it looked pretty lame-o myself after before AND after figuring out what they were writing. 

Thanks again!

Nick

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is just a declaration. Declaration consists of the initial part (*declaration specifier*) that describes the "basic" part of the type, and a comma-separated sequence of *declarators*, each of which declares a separate name and, possibly, modifies the basic type. In C you can declare multiple names using the same declaration specifier

```
int count, x, *intptr;
```

is equivalent to

```
int count;
int x;
int *intptr;
```

Optionally, you can add an initializer to each declarator or to some fo them. So

```
int count = 10, x, *intptr;
```

is the same as

```
int count = 10;
int x;
int *intptr;
```

That's all there's to it.

Answer (score 3):

It's equivilent to

```
int count = 10;
int x;
int *intPtr;
```

Comment: is it just me or does this seem out of step with some of the syntax laid out in general for c?

Comment: It's just you.  Initialized declarators are not the same as assignment expressions, and commas between declarators are not treated the same as commas between expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common source of errors for both novice *and expert* C (and C++) programmers, together with *comma operator*. 
Usual confusion:

```
int* p, pp;
pp = malloc( sizeof( int ) * N ); /* oops pp is just int, not a pointer */
...
int x;
x = 12, 13, 14; /* and the value of the x is ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma means, that x is also an int, and *intPtr is also int (and intPtr is pointer to int).
Its like:

```
Aunts Mary, Jane, Daryl;
Mary is stupid;
Jane is Old;
Daryl is same as Mary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its like

```
int count, x;
```

except that count is being initilized to 10